# I'm creating a run pace calculator and for some reason I have to hit enter twice to get the minutes and seconds. How can I get this to work?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, asynchronous, state, enter

I think this has to do with state is asynchronous. I have tried dispatching a keyboard event so it is like pushing enter twice but I couldn't get that to work and have also tried using useEffect but that doesn't seem to work either.Also I realized I don't need Number in front of everything. Could this be affecting the code? How do I get around this? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import { useState } from 'react';
import './css/paceCalculator.css';

const PaceCalculator = () => {
    const [distance, setDistance] = useState(0);
    const [paceTime, setPaceTime] = useState({
        hours: (0),
        minutes: (0),
        seconds: (0)
    })
    const [pace, setPace] = useState(0);
    const [runPace, setRunPace] = useState(0);
    const handleChange = (e) => {
        setDistance(Number(e.target.value));
    }

    const handlePaceChange = (e) =>{
        const value = e.target.value;
        setPaceTime({
            ...paceTime,
            [e.target.name]: value
        })
    }

    const calculatePace = () =>{
        let minuteFraction = paceTime.seconds / 60

        console.log([(Number(paceTime.hours) * 60 + Number(paceTime.minutes) + minuteFraction) / Number(distance)]);

      setRunPace((Number(paceTime.hours) *60 + Number(paceTime.minutes)+ minuteFraction) / Number(distance));
      let convertAfterDecimal = (runPace - Math.floor(runPace)) * 60;

    setPace(Number(convertAfterDecimal.toFixed(0)));
    }

    const handlePaceSubmit =  (e) =>{
        e.preventDefault();
        calculatePace();
    }


    

    return (
        <div>
            <h1>Pace Calculator</h1>
            <h2>Distance</h2>
            <form onSubmit={handlePaceSubmit}>
                <input
                    type="number"
                    placeholder="enter distance"
                    name="distance"
                    onChange={handleChange}
                    value={distance}
                />
            </form>
            <h2>Time</h2>
            <form onSubmit={handlePaceSubmit}>
                <input
                    className="=time"
                    type="number"
                    onChange={handlePaceChange}
                    value={paceTime.time}
                    size="5"
                    placeholder="hh"
                    name="hours"
                />
                </form>
                <form onSubmit={handlePaceSubmit}>
                <input
                    className="=time"
                    type="number"
                    onChange={handlePaceChange}
                    value={paceTime.minutes}
                    size="5"
                    placeholder="mm"
                    name="minutes"
                />
                </form>
                <form onSubmit={handlePaceSubmit}>
                <input
                    className="=time"
                    type="text"
                    onChange={handlePaceChange}
                    value={paceTime.seconds}
                    size="5"
                    placeholder="ss"
                    name="seconds"
                />
            </form>
            <h2>Pace</h2>
            {/* <form>
            <input
                    type="text"
                    placeholder="minutes/mile"
                />
            </form> */}
            <h1>{`${Math.floor(runPace)} m ${pace} s`}</h1>
        </div>
    )

}

export default PaceCalculator;
```

Answer (score 0):

found a solution

```
const calculatePace = () => {
    let minuteFraction = paceTime.seconds / 60

    let getMinutes = ((Number(paceTime.hours) * 60 + Number(paceTime.minutes) + minuteFraction) / Number(paceTime.distance));

    setSecondsPace(((getMinutes - Math.floor(getMinutes)) * 60).toFixed(0))

    setRunPace(Math.floor(getMinutes));


}
```